# Nginx returns 404 not found error on sub pages

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, configuration, server

Below is my config file and my website url is https://www.fossbytes.tk/login/ which i want to access but i failed to access the sub pages in the nginx.In apache i am using  all override all;  command to access all the pages and subpages but it is not working in case of nginx.

how to fix the below config file and access all the sub pages in nginx without htaccess

```
server {
ssl_dhparam  /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fossbytes.tk.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/fossbytes.tk.key;
location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

        server_name fossbytes.tk www.fossbytes.tk;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
   }

server {

        # SSL configuration


    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
         include snippets/ssl-fossbytes.tk.conf;
         include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php login.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

autoindex off;

        server_name fossbyte.tk;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
access_log off; # do not log access to static files
    expires max;
}

                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
 #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {

        }

location ~* .(woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

my error log

```
2017/02/24 11:42:38 [error] 32739#32739: *1 open() "/var/www/html/affiliate/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /affiliate/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "fossbytes.tk", referrer: "https://fossbytes.tk/affiliate/css/font-awesome.min.css"
2017/02/24 11:42:38 [error] 32739#32739: *8 open() "/var/www/html/affiliate/js/angular-aria.min.js.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /affiliate/js/angular-aria.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", host: "fossbytes.tk"
2017/02/24 11:42:38 [error] 32739#32739: *11 open() "/var/www/html/affiliate/js/angular-route.min.js.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /affiliate/js/angular-route.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", host: "fossbytes.tk"
2017/02/24 11:42:38 [error] 32739#32739: *7 open() "/var/www/html/affiliate/js/angular-animate.min.js.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /affiliate/js/angular-animate.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", host: "fossbytes.tk"
2017/02/24 11:42:39 [error] 32739#32739: *9 open() "/var/www/html/affiliate/js/angular-messages.min.js.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /affiliate/js/angular-messages.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", host: "fossbytes.tk"
2017/02/24 11:42:39 [error] 32739#32739: *5 open() "/var/www/html/affiliate/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /affiliate/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0 HTTP/2.0", host: "www.fossbytes.tk", referrer: "https://www.fossbytes.tk/affiliate/css/font-awesome.min.css"
2017/02/24 11:42:43 [error] 32739#32739: *5 open() "/var/www/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", host: "www.fossbytes.tk", referrer: "https://www.fossbytes.tk/"
2017/02/24 11:45:14 [error] 32739#32739: *5 "/var/www/html/login/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.60.31.120, server: fossbyte.tk, request: "GET /login/ HTTP/2.0", host: "www.fossbytes.tk"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how i configured the file for [nginx](http://www.kalilinuxhack.com) and it works perfectly fine for me.

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 128.199.143.50;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    }


    location /affiliate_services {
try_files $uri $uri /affiliate_services/index.php;
rewrite ^/affiliate_services/(.*)$ /affiliate_services/index.php?url=$1 last;

}

location /affiliate {
try_files $uri $uri /affiliate/index.php;
#rewrite ^/cshelpdesk/(.*)$ /cshelpdesk/index.html last;
 }

location /api {
#try_files $uri $uri /api/flipkart_api.php;
#rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/flipkart_api.php last;
 }

 # Expire rules for static content

# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
  expires -1;
  # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
}

# Feed
location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
  expires 1h;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

     # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have error in location try to use

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Are you reload server? What access log says?

Comment: i am using <directory> all override all;</directory> in .htaccess in apache server

Comment: What does 'sudo nginx -t' say

Comment: But this is config for nginx not apache. Nginx does not use .htaccess at all

Comment: root@OM:/etc/nginx# sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: i can access homepages link but i am receving error on sub pages.

Comment: Try to create new virtual host with minimum configuration and check if it works. This is they way how it must to work

Comment: Error log is explicit you don't have files on the server that you are trying to open. Nginx config is OK

Comment: do i have to list each and every directory of my website on configuration file to access the subpage